# 'int' object is not callable error ,While True Loop

Tags: python-3.x

## Math Quiz

```
import random
import math
import operator

def questions():
    # Gets the name of the user
    name= input("What is your name")
    for i in range(10):
    #Generates the questions
        number1 = random.randint(0,100)
        number2 = random.randint(1,10)
    #Creates a Dictionary with the symbols as the keys and the opertations as the values
        Operands ={'+':operator.add,
                   '-':operator.sub,
                   '*':operator.mul,
                   '/':operator.truediv}
        #Creast a list containing a tuple which contains the dictionary keys       
        Ops= random.choice(list(Operands.keys()))
        # Makes the  Answer variable availabe to the whole program for later use
        global answer
        # Gets the answer
        answer= Operands.get(Ops)(number1,number2) # Returns a value for the given key
        # Makes the  Sum variable  avialbe to the whole program for later use
        global Sum
        # Ask the user the question 
        Sum = ('What is {} {} {} {}?'.format(number1,Ops,number2,name))
        print (Sum)
```

## Exception Handling

```
    while True:
        try:
            global UserAnswer  # Makes the UserAnswer varialbe availbe to the whole program for later use
            UserAnswer= float(input()) # Convertss the input into a floating number that can be operated
            break
        except ValueError:
            print(" Oops! That was not a valid number. Try again..." )

    return answer


def askQuestion():
    answer =questions()
    guess = UserAnswer
    return guess == answer






def score():
            score = 0
            for i in range(10):
                correct= questions()
                if UserAnswer == answer :
                    score =score + l1
                    print("You got it right \n ")
                else:
                    print("You got it wrong \n")

            print("You got {} out of 10 \n".format(score))     

    ok= True
    while ok== True:
        questions()
        score()
        WhichClass(name,score)

        ask=(input("Another ? "))

        if ask in ('y','yes','Y'):
            ok=True
        else:
            ok=False
```

I have written a program to that generates a quick. I have added a while True loop to run the program again if required. However when I run through the program I get the following error:

```
What is 93 - 3?
90
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Family/Google Drive/V4.4.py", line 114, in <module>
    score()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What is causing my error.

Comment: Please post the whole code. Right now, the problematic code is missing from the question.

Comment: I have added in the remaining code

Comment: Both your function and your variable are called `score`. Rename at least one, and the problem might disappear.

Comment: Oh, it seems the code you posted originally was sufficient. Only the indentation was incorrect.

Comment: No, wait. The traceback has no traces of the frame for `score`. So the exception cannot be raised inside `def score():`. Could you please properly indent your code and tell us where line 114 is?